# Parse Server with React Native

Tags: react-native, parse-server

I'm trying to integrate Parse server with React native, so I followed the [documentation](http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/) and I added parse/react-native package but it keeps throwing this error **"TypeError: _reactNative3.default.setAsyncStorage is not a function**

Here is my snack for more details https://snack.expo.io/BkWo7v7sG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that your [`Parse SDK`](http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/) is not `installed / imported` correctly.

This is true because in your `package.json` you are using

```
 "parse/react-native": "1.11.1"
```

**which is not a package.**

You need to install [Parse](http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/) via *npm / yarn* as `yarn add parse` or modify your `package.json` as

```
"parse": "1.11.1"
```

, *and follow the steps*, then it would work.

Comment: Thank you for your response, so I can import Parse from 'parse' instead of 'parse/react-native" ??

Comment: No, you need to install  `parse` and not `parse/react-native` in your `package.json`, `parse/react-native` is not a package